# lookbehind alternative way

Tags: javascript, regex

This code doesn't work in safari 15, so need another way to solve it without lookbehind

```js
const re = /(?<!\\)(?<!-)-/g;
const str = '20-30--40\\---50--60';
console.log(str.split(re));
```

output:

```js
['20', '30', '-40\\---50', '-60']
```

---

What this code does:
Need to split the string into parts.
For example.

```js
"10-20" -> ['10', '20']
```

but need to split only the first '-' and keep all '-' before the value, i.e.

```js
"10---20" -> ['10', '--20']
```

and finally, it should be possible to escape with `\`:

```js
"10---20--30"  -> ['10', '--20', '-30']
"10---20\--30" -> ['10', '--20\--30']
```

I don't know much about regex, chatgpt and alternatives couldn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in two steps: First replace the `-` where you want to split with a character that doesn't exist in the string and then split on that character. I'm using `\t` here:

```js
var strings = ["10-20", "10---20", "10---20--30", "10---20\\--30"];

for(str of strings) {
  console.log(str);
  console.log(str.replace(/(\d)-/g, "$1\t").replace(/\\/g, "").split(/\t/));
}
```

Note that you need `\\` in the string to make it include the `\`s.
It first replaces the `-`, then removes any `\\` and finally splits. If you want to keep the `\` in the string, just remove `.replace(/\\/g, "")`.

Comment: whata... man... its AMAZING and so easy i very thank you, you really save my day

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a lookbehind assertion, you can use a capture group instead to keep the values that you are splitting on.

After splitting remove the empty entries.

```
(.*?[^\n\\-])-
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.*?` Match any character, as few as possible
  - `[^\n\\-]` Match a character other than `\` or `-` or a newline
- `)` Close group 1
- `-` Match literally

```js
const regex = /(.*?[^\n\\-])-/;
const strings = [
  "20-30--40\\---50--60",
  "10-20",
  "10---20",
  "10---20--30",
  "10---20\\--30"
]

strings.forEach(s =>
  console.log(
    s.split(regex)
    .filter(Boolean)
  )
)
```

Comment: Nice one!......

Answer (score 1):

The following [regex](https://regex101.com/r/zN0GYo/2) does what is needed.

```
(?:^|-)(-*(?:(?:\\.+?)?[^\n\\-]+)+)
```

```
(?:          group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------
  ^            the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------
 |            OR
--------------------------------------------------------
  -            '-'
--------------------------------------------------------
)            end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------
(            group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------
  -*           '-' (0 or more times (matching the most
               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------
  (?:          group, but do not capture (1 or more
               times (matching the most amount
               possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------
    (?:          group, but do not capture (optional
                 (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------
      \\           '\'
--------------------------------------------------------
      .+?          any character except \n (1 or more
                   times (matching the least amount
                   possible))
--------------------------------------------------------
    )?           end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------
    [^\n\\-]+    any character except: '\n' (newline),
                 '\', '-' (1 or more times (matching the
                 most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------
  )+           end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------
)            end of \1
```

```js
const re = /(?:^|-)(-*(?:(?:\\.+?)?[^\n\\-]+)+)/gm;
const str = `20-30--40\\---50--60
170-42`;
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(re),
                       it => it[1]));
```